# Set CSS half fixed/half scroll layout to 100% height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My layout has sections that are opposites of each other, there are four of them. They contain an aside and a main container. The aside stays fixed to the screen, whichever side of the screen it is on. I want to change it so that the aside takes up 100% of the screen height. Right now when I try to change its height explicitly to 100% or vh, it breaks the layout. The main container will be the height of the contents it contains, just as it is now. (aside stays fixed until main has scrolled to end. At this point the whole screen scrolls to next section, now inverted with main and aside switching sides.

This is what the layout should function like... http://melaniedaveid.com/

Edit: updated code:
https://codepen.io/marti2221/pen/LLKpbp

```
<section>
    <aside>
        <div id="container-black">
            <p id="hello">Hello</p>
            <div id="container-nav">
                <p id="how">How</p>
                <p id="are">are</p>
                <p id="you">you</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
<main>
<div class="inner">
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <p>
  main ainadf asdfhkad dsafdsd  dfds s s adfj adfja  dx nadf asdfnadf asdfhkad dsafdsd  dfds s s adfj adfja  dxadf asdfhkad dsafdsd  dfds adfj adfja  dx
    </p>
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <p>
  main ainadf asdfhkad dsafdsd  dfds s s adfj adfja  dx nadf asdfnadf asdfhkad dsafdsd  dfds s s adfj adfja  dxadf asdfhkad dsafdsd  dfds adfj adfja  dx
    </p>
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <p>
  main ainadf asdfhkad dsafdsd  dfds s s adfj adfja  dx nadf asdfnadf asdfhkad dsafdsd  dfds s s adfj adfja  dxadf asdfhkad dsafdsd  dfds adfj adfja  dx
    </p>
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <p>
  main ainadf asdfhkad dsafdsd  dfds s s adfj adfja  dx nadf asdfnadf asdfhkad dsafdsd  dfds s s adfj adfja  dxadf asdfhkad dsafdsd  dfds adfj adfja  dx
    </p>

        </div>
    </main>
</section>


* {box-sizing:border-box;}

section {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
overflow-y: scroll;
margin: auto;
display: flex;
background: gray;
}

section:nth-child(even) main {
order: -1;
}

aside,main {
flex: 1 0 50%;
}

aside{
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
justify-content: center;
}
#container-black{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
justify-content: flex-end;
}

#hello{
background: blue;
flex:.6;
align-self: center;

}
#container-nav {
background:white;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
}

aside,.inner {
padding: .5em;
}

aside {
background: #eee;
position: sticky;
top: 0; left: 0;
}

main {
position: relative;
color: white;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

Also, if there is any way to get rid of the internal scroll. Same layout, just one scroll bar.

Comment: ok it appears it is just the height that is causing the issue.

Comment: Ok, now after your edit, do you or don't you want internal scrollbars? The new pen still shows them...

Comment: still would let to get rid of them if possible. But getting the main/aside containers to take up 100% of the screen was the point of this post.

Answer (score 0):

**REWRITE**

After you changed the codepen my answer needed a rewriting as basically the rules had changed.

**CSS**

- To be able to get a better understanding of your CSS I moved things up and down a bit to get a "logical flow".
- Put rules on the same line to condense the snippet view
- Added comment to the code where I made changes
- Added **responsiveness for mobile/desktop** by creating flex wrap on **20rem** for display widths smaller than **40rem**

**HTML**

- Put `<h1>` and `<articles` in their own container `<div>`
- Used above modification to create a **hidden scrollbar** effect by hiding the scrollbars of `main` with class `.ns-outer` and enabling container `<div>` scrollbars, but hidden from view with class `.ns-inner`

**Link**

[Codepen "stackoverflow 45178572"](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/XgLgWO)

**DO NOT expect this code runs as smooth as the given example site**, which uses a few external libraries, but sure should point you in the right direction.

**Snippet**

```css
 *   { box-sizing: border-box }

/* ADD, to remove (HTML default) page outer margin */
body { margin: 0 }

/*
    MOD/ADD: only on larger displays (width>640) because content will wrap
             and this would mess up nice LEFT/RIGHT inverted layout.
         
*/
@media screen and (min-width: 40rem) { /* 320px + 320px, See "aside, main" below */
    section:nth-child(even) main { order: -1 }
}
section             { display: flex; 
                      flex-flow: row wrap; /* ADD enable it to wrap on small displays */

                      width: 100%; height: 100vh; /* MOD 685px to 100vh */
                      margin: 0 auto; /* MOD to "0 auto", will center itself in body. (Change width to 80% to see effect) */
/* REMOVE             overflow-y: scroll; */

                      background: gray }

aside               { display: flex; overflow: hidden; justify-content: center;
                      background: #eee; top: 0; left: 0 }
aside, .inner       { padding: .5em }

aside, main         { flex: 1 1 20rem } /* MOD so they wrap on screens smaller than 320px + 320px */
                                        /* Works in conjunction with "@media section..." */

main                { position: relative; color: white }
article, h1         { margin: 15px 100px }
h1                  { margin-top: 50px }

#container-black    { display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%; width: 50%; justify-content: flex-end }
#hello              { background: blue; flex: .6; align-self: center } /* removed "sticky" */
#container-nav      { background: white; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-around }

/* nice little hidden scollbar trick */
.ns-outer           { position: relative; overflow: hidden }
.ns-inner           { position: absolute; overflow: auto; top: 0; right: -17px; bottom: 0; left: 0 }
```

```html
<section>
  <aside>
    <div id="container-black">
      <p id="hello">Hello</p>
      <div id="container-nav">
        <p id="how">How</p>
        <p id="are">are</p>
        <p id="you">you</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main class="ns-outer">
    <div class="ns-inner">
      <h1>First heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.</article>
      <h1>Second heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in Nulla facilisi. Etiam sagittis enim sapien,
        in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi.</article>
      <h1>Third heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.</article>
      <h1>Fourth heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.</article>
    </div>
  </main>
</section>
<section>
  <aside>
    <div id="container-black">
      <p id="hello">Hello</p>
      <div id="container-nav">
        <p id="how">How</p>
        <p id="are">are</p>
        <p id="you">you</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main class="ns-outer">
    <div class="ns-inner">
      <h1>First heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.</article>
      <h1>Second heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in Nulla facilisi. Etiam sagittis enim sapien,
        in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi.</article>
      <h1>Third heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.</article>
      <h1>Fourth heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.</article>
    </div>
  </main>
</section>
<section>
  <aside>
    <div id="container-black">
      <p id="hello">Hello</p>
      <div id="container-nav">
        <p id="how">How</p>
        <p id="are">are</p>
        <p id="you">you</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main class="ns-outer">
    <div class="ns-inner">
      <h1>First heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.</article>
      <h1>Second heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in Nulla facilisi. Etiam sagittis enim sapien,
        in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi.</article>
      <h1>Third heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.</article>
      <h1>Fourth heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.</article>
    </div>
  </main>
</section>
<section>
  <aside>
    <div id="container-black">
      <p id="hello">Hello</p>
      <div id="container-nav">
        <p id="how">How</p>
        <p id="are">are</p>
        <p id="you">you</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main class="ns-outer">
    <div class="ns-inner">
      <h1>First heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.</article>
      <h1>Second heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in Nulla facilisi. Etiam sagittis enim sapien,
        in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi.</article>
      <h1>Third heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.</article>
      <h1>Fourth heading</h1>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec
        lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.</article>
    </div>
  </main>
</section>
```

Comment: Wont getting rid of the overflow property ruin the entire functionality of the half scroll layout? I still want everything to function the same, I just need each alternating section to take up the entire screen.

Comment: Nope, I edited the pen and it worked fine for me... But you will run into a few more problems if you want it fully responsive. What are you going to do on screen with a width < 480px? (most smartphones)

Comment: So I assume its probably that overflow property that interferes with the height?

Comment: https://codepen.io/marti2221/pen/XgLmzr This is the one that functions correctly but as you can see. the sections do not take up 100% of the viewing area

Comment: that does not have half that scrolls. I am looking for the half with the content to scroll (because it will take up more space than 100% of the screen height. The other side (aside) will be the equal to the height of the screen, and 50% of its width.

Comment: Thanks and will do! This code is pretty much exactly what Im looking for. I love the little overflow trick you used to get the main content to scroll. Is there any way to get this to scroll when youre hovering on the fixed side as well? So that no matter where the mouse is located, the main content must scroll to its end in order to move to the next section.

Comment: And actually now that I look at it closer, this still has the height of the light grey box set to 685px, which is precisely what I want changed. I want that equal to the screen height. That still has yet to be changed. Thats all Im looking for. I can work on the responsiveness of the layout after I solve this problem... getting the heigth of my fixed container to take up the whole screen height.

Comment: Not the 685px it is currently set to. This was just a guess to set it close to the height of the screen.

Comment: The same trick should work for `<aside>` and `container-black`, Shoot, I just discovered you are using IDs. Quickly change those to `class`names!!! IDs MUST be unique!. And 100vh should work too. Just fiddle, you'll get there.

Comment: ok so 100vh should theoretically work for the aside height with this layout?

Comment: ok I changed the ids to class' and did the same for the selectors. got rid of a height for the overall section container and changed the height of aside to 100vh. That did change the height to the correct size. However now it does not scroll on the right hand side of the page. So the aside container scrolls up with the content.

Comment: So now all I need is for the each aside container to stay static until it reaches the bottom of its section (or until the main container reaches the end of its content, same thing). This is what i have https://codepen.io/marti2221/pen/QgXoMr

Comment: First you need to start using MY version of the PEN, I won't keep checking whether you made the changes properly (I have other things too). I changed `section:height` from **685px** to **100vh**, now you clone my pen and mod `aside` and `container-black` to behave like `main` and `div`. I am really done editting for now.